# PHP foreach not working when iterating query result

Tags: php, mysql

Array to string conversion is thrown when I try to get a specific id and don't let me save the form. i just need the id of 'intervaloHorario' in order to autofill a field,but i don't know what am i doing wrong. Please give me a hand.

**Error**

Severity: 4096

Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

**Model function**

```
    public function get_idintervalo($idCitas) {

            $query = $this->db->query('SELECT intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario FROM intervaloshorarios INNER JOIN citas '
                    . 'ON intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario = citas.idIntervaloHorario '
                    . 'WHERE citas.idCitas = ' . $idCitas . ';');

            return $query->result();
}
```

**Controller**

```
$query = $this->Intervalos_Model->get_idintervalo($idCitas);


        if ($crud->getState() == "add") {
//It's wroking fine getting this
            $crud->change_field_type('idCitas', 'hidden', $idCitas);

foreach ($query as $key) {
            //Is not working fine (throws array to string conversion)
            $crud->change_field_type('idIntervaloHorario', 'hidden', $key);
        }
```

Comment: I think you can do a `gettype($query)` to see the type of `$query` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using CodeIgnitor Framework. You should write

```
foreach ($query as $key) {
    //Is not working fine (throws array to string conversion)
    $crud->change_field_type('idIntervaloHorario', 'hidden', $key->idIntervaloHorario);
}
```

because $query stores the query resultset in objects and $key is an object here.
For more see manual https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/results.html

Comment: Thank you very much!! I am new with this and i've been looking for days a working answer!! you're a crack!

Answer (score 0):

Is this OpenCart?
If so use:

```
return $query->rows;
```

to get an array of returned rows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! i got what i was looking for thanks to @simurgrai